# Custom URL in Yii

Tags: php, url, yii, seo

I want to configure custom URL in Yii . I am stuck at one last step .
This is how I create the URL :

```
$a->url =  Yii::app()->createUrl('view/profile',array('uid'=>$a->userid,'type'=>$a->type,'specialty'=>$specialty,'locality'=>$locality)) ;
```

This is how I have the rule in config file :

```
'profile<uid:\w+>_<type:\w+>/'=>'view/profile,
```

This works fine except that the URL which is generated is :

```
http://localhost/dev/profile122_doctor?specialty=Cardiology&locality=Times+Square
```

I want the URL to be cleaner , something along these lines :

```
http://localhost/dev/profile122_doctor/specialty-Cardiology-near-Times-Square
```

Can this be done ? Any suggestions ? Btw only uid and type variables are actually required for the URL to work correctly . Rest of the info is needed for the purpose of SEO .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own URL Rule class, this way you'll have more liberty on the syntax:

[Using Custom URL Rule Classes in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes)

Comment: I configured the class , however I am stuck again , how do I specify it in the config file so that the rule is applied only in a particular case ? How do I specify the same when using Yii::app()->createUrl to create the url ?

Comment: What is your particular case?
You should put your newly created in first and the default one after so if the particular rule is not applicable then you'll fallback on the other

Comment: My particular scenario is the one in the question above , everything else is of this type : '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
I did change the placement (placing the custom class array on top) however it ends up applying the custom class rule to all cases then .

Comment: In your custom rule you should check that the model is the good one, you have the good params etc to be sure it applies only to the desired model with the good params!